# Solving Schmitt trigger circuit using the superposition theorem

Tags: operational-amplifier, comparator, schmitt-trigger, non-linear

In order to solve a Schmitt trigger circuit implemented with an op-amp (or a comparator) connected in positive feedback, this [wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schmitt_trigger#Non-inverting_Schmitt_trigger) uses the superposition theorem.

My question is : why can we use the superposition principle in this situation? Superposition is a property of **linear** system and this one is clearly nonlinear since positive feedback involves hysteresis and saturation...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Wiki article is using superposition correctly. It starts by assuming the output is in one state, then **assuming the output remains in that state**, calculates the comparator input with respect to the circuit input. It uses this relationship to determine the input level (producing zero volts at the comparator) to determine the trigger point at the specified state. It then does the same for the other state. What it does not do is to model the behavior of the circuit as a trigger point is passed - it only identifies what the trigger points are.

Comment: Addendum, which you've alluded to: this process makes two separate linear circuits. This means superposition can be used.